# Matplotlib: x-axis values instead of indices

Tags: python, matplotlib

While plotting the sinus of x for x in [0,2*pi] and plotting it using matplotlib, I did this:

```
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

but the result was

[image: sin(x)]

where the x-axis does not display the value of x, but the index of x in the array. How can I tell `matplotlib.pyplot` to give me the actual x-values `(0.1, 0.2, ... pi, pi +0.1, .... 2*pi)` as one would expect from a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair to matplotlib, you never told it anything about `x`. Try this:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `y = np.sin(x)` for `y = [np.sin(i) for i in x]`. [image]

Comment: That would only change the value of y. The actual problem was that I plotted `y` without giving the x-values as proposed by @Arne

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Thought the mistake was another one